# Preventing rising second event

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-8, windows-8.1

Hello i have a next code:

When thumbnail is tapped i have to download file if it doesn't exist localy, or open if exists.

The problem is that if i make very quick two taps - it downloads same file two times - how to prevent this?

As you can see i tried using bool - didn't help.

Tried also using private static SemaphoreSlim TapSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1); - didn't help

```
public bool IsCurrentlyDownloading = false;

private async void assetThumbnail_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await OpenOrDownload();
}

private async Task OpenOrDownload()
{
    if (FileIsDownloaded == true)
    {
        string filename = Util.GetLocalFileName(CustomerAsset.file.id, "CustomerAssetFile");
        var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
        options.DisplayApplicationPicker = false;
        var sampleFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(sampleFile, options);
    }
    else
    {
        if (!IsCurrentlyDownloading)
        {
            IsCurrentlyDownloading = true;
            DownloadFiles();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a flag (bool, sync object, something) to mark that the downloading or displaying operation is in progress and in this case do not show it.

Rather conceptually, something like this:

```
public bool IsCurrentlyDownloading = false;
bool isWorking = false;

private async void assetThumbnail_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!isWorking)
        await OpenOrDownload();
}

private async Task OpenOrDownload()
{
    isWorking = true;

    if (FileIsDownloaded == true)
    {
        string filename = Util.GetLocalFileName(CustomerAsset.file.id, "CustomerAssetFile");
        var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
        options.DisplayApplicationPicker = false;
        var sampleFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(sampleFile, options);
    }
    else
    {
        if (!IsCurrentlyDownloading)
        {
            IsCurrentlyDownloading = true;
            DownloadFiles();
        }
    }

    isWorking = false;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't do, it still enters OpenOrDownload

Comment: But i have managed to fix it, lets say you pointed me a right direction. Thanks. The problem was that i was downloading 2 files: thumbnail and a file - thumbnail downloaded faster and removed the Working flag